# How to access the friend class method?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, friend

I am new to C++. Please have a look at the following code

**Position.h**

```
#pragma once
class Position
{
public:
    Position(int x, int y, int z);
    Position();
    ~Position();

    void display();

private:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

**Position.cpp**

```
#include "Position.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Position::Position(int x, int y, int z)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}

Position::Position(){}


Position::~Position(void)
{
}
```

**GameComponent.h**

```
#pragma once
#include<time.h>

class GameComponent
{
public:
    GameComponent(int);
    GameComponent();
    ~GameComponent(void);

    virtual void update(const tm*);
    friend class Position;

private:
    int id;
};
```

**GameComponent.cpp**

```
#include "GameComponent.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "DrawableGameComponent.h"

using namespace std;

GameComponent::GameComponent(int v):id(v)
{

}

GameComponent::GameComponent(){}


GameComponent::~GameComponent(void)
{

}

void GameComponent::update(const tm* time)
{
    cout << "ID : " << id << endl;
    cout << "Update: " << time->tm_hour << ":" << time->tm_min << ":" << time->tm_sec << endl;

    //Position::displayPositions();
}

void Position::display()
{
    cout << "X" << x << "Y" << y << "Z" << z << endl;
}
```

I need to access the method `display()` which is belongs to friend class `Position` of class `GameComponent` inside GameComponent's `update(const tm* time)` method. Actually what I am trying to do is to access the private data members of class `Position`. How can I do this? Please help

Comment: Please look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

Comment: Friendship is not a two-way relationship, you got it the other way around...

Comment: Also, display is current declared public, so there's no need for friendship here.

Answer (score 6):

C++ friendship works the other way: if `GameComponent` declares `Position` as a friend it means that `Position` has access to all the private methods of the `GameCompenent`. What you need is exactly the opposite: call `Position` private methods from `GameComponent`

So if `Position::displayPositions()` is the private method of the Position class that you want to access from GameComponent then you can declare `GameComponent` as a friend of `Position`:

```
class Position
{
    friend class GameComponent;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make `GameComponent` a friend of `Position`, the way you currently have it allows `Position` to access `GameComponent`'s private and protected members, [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class)'s simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a friend class, you allow this class to access your non public data. In your example, `GameComponent`allow to a `Position` class to access to `GameComponent` non public methods and attributes.

I think that your pourpose is access `Position` from `GameComponent`, so your declaration must be inside `Position`class making `GameComponent` a friendly class (Note: you don't really need this because `Position::display()` is public :

```
class Position
{
   .....
   friend class GameComponent;

};
```

Whit this declaration, you may access `Position`components from `GameComponent`. But, `Position::display()`function is not an static function, you need to instanciate a Position object: something like this:

```
class GameComponent
{
    protected:
        Position pos;
};
```

and

```
void GameComponent::update(const tm* time)
{
    cout << "ID : " << id << endl;
    cout << "Update: " << time->tm_hour << ":" << time->tm_min << ":" << time->tm_sec << endl;

    pos.displayPositions();
}
```

If you have no `Position` attributes belonging to `GameComponent`you must pass as parameter:

```
void GameComponent::update(const tm* time, Position & pos)
{
    cout << "ID : " << id << endl;
    cout << "Update: " << time->tm_hour << ":" << time->tm_min << ":" << time->tm_sec << endl;

    pos::displayPositions();
}
```

Besides, is a good practice implement `Position::display` function in Position.cpp